# Why doesn't nomenclature show up in TOC using this custom class?

Tags: table-of-contents, document-classes, texshop, nomenclature

Background:

I'm trying to use a LaTeX class found [HERE](http://www.ryerson.ca/~jvl/ryethesis/ryethesis/ryethesis.zip)
to create a thesis. The class has a scheme for enabling/disabling the creation of a "List of Symbols" using LaTeX's nomenclature package. When I typeset LaTeX, run the nomenclature makeindex command, and typeset LaTeX again, the List of Symbols page is successfully generated.

Problem:

The List of Symbols (nomenclature) does not appear in the Table of Contents and I can't figure out how to make it appear. I'm new to LaTeX and I'm a little lost when it comes to searching through the .tex file and class file trying to figure out what's wrong.

Environment details:

TeXShop 3.48.1 on Mac OS 10.10.1

MWE .tex:

```
\documentclass[draft,los]{ryethesis}
\includenomenclature

\author{Me}
\title{Thesis}
\degreeName{Doctor of Philosophy}
\degreeYear{1847}
\program{Education}
\abstract{}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\nomenclature{a}{length of adjacent side}
\nomenclature{b}{length of opposite side}
\nomenclature{c}{length of hypotenuse}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

MWE .dtx snippets

```
\ifthenelse{\boolean{@ryenomenclature}}{%
\RequirePackage{nomencl}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}
\makenomenclature
}{}

\newcommand{\ryethesis@insertnom}{%
\ifthenelse{\boolean{@ryenomenclature}}{\ryethesis@clearpage\printnomenclature}{}
}
```

Later on in the file, this is called:

```
\ryethesis@insertnom
```

This produces an 8 page document mostly containing template information set up by the class. The portions of interest are the "List of Symbols" page which features the a,b,c symbols shown above in the \nomenclature lines, and the "Contents" page which does not list an entry for "List of Symbols"

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It's tedious to get 'custom' classes downloaded and functionally

Comment: Right after `\ListoSymbols` (or what ever the command is called) try `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Symbols}` (perhaps with a preceeding `\phantomsection`)

Comment: I have added a MWE in terms of the .tex file. I looked at the .dtx file for the class and I can't say I know where to begin stripping it down to something I can post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert the following code before `\includenomenclature`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\ryethesis@insertnom}{%
\ifthenelse{\boolean{@ryenomenclature}}{\ryethesis@clearpage\phantomsection\label{listofsymbols}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textit{\mdseries{}List
    of Symbols}}\printnomenclature}{}
}
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[draft,los]{ryethesis}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\ryethesis@insertnom}{%
\ifthenelse{\boolean{@ryenomenclature}}{\ryethesis@clearpage\phantomsection\label{listofsymbols}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textit{\mdseries{}List
    of Symbols}}\printnomenclature}{}
}
\makeatother

\includenomenclature

\author{Me}
\title{Thesis}
\degreeName{Doctor of Philosophy}
\degreeYear{1847}
\program{Education}
\abstract{}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\nomenclature{a}{length of adjacent side}
\nomenclature{b}{length of opposite side}
\nomenclature{c}{length of hypotenuse}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That works perfectly. Can I trouble you for a brief explanation or a referral to documentation somewhere?

Comment: @SVC I've just searched for other lists to see how they are defined in the `.cls` file (e.g. the "List of Plates", see the definition of `\ryethesis@insertlop`)

Comment: @SVC BTW: `\includenomenclature` is not needed since you are passing the option `los` to the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can the `intoc` option when importing `nomencl`:

```
\RequirePackage[intoc]{nomencl}
```

If using `usepackage` to import (inside the `documentclass`):

```
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
```